# Strange space in unorder list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

i am trying design a thumbnail with the latest pictures uploaded in my site. In the project use bootstrap twitter.
The thumbnail works fine, except by a little detail. The thumbnail contains 3 rows with 4 columns, in the second row, exist a space in the first,second and third list place. It is a screen:
[image]

The html code is generated with Smarty, it is the code, and works fine:

```
<ul class="thumbnails lastFotos">
{foreach from=$last_fotos item="foto"}
     <li class="span1"><a class="thumbnail"><img src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/img/galeria/{$foto.Nombre}"  alt="{$foto.Nombre}"/></a></li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Thumbnails, thumbnail and span1 are classes of Bootswrap, whereas that lastFotos is a class created for my, to change some configuration of Bootstrap:

```
ul.lastFotos{ margin-left: 22px; }

ul.lastFotos li{ display: inline; margin-bottom: 7px; margin-left: 5px; }

ul.lastFotos li a{ border-radius: 0; padding: 2px; }

ul.lastFotos li a:hover{ border-color: #8e84b8; }
```

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because image are of different sizes, give a `height` to `list` or `image` it will fix it

like

```
ul.lastFotos li {height:60px;}
```

or

```
ul.lastFotos li img{width:60px;height:60px;}
```

Comment: teikirisi, 6 minutes remaining ;)